# Edit_SetInputMode, win32 API

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to change the input mode to a given window. 
Searching i found the Edit_SetInputMode function, but when i run it, it always returns 0 ( fails) .
The MSDN documentation doesn't seem be to revealing... Any ideas anyone

Thank you

Dan

Comment: Is this question about Windows Mobile? If so, you might want to tag it as Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The correct terminology is probably focus: See [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312(VS.85).aspx)

---

Oh! I see where you are coming from. There is no such thing as Edit_SetInputMode - unless you are developing for embedded Windows that is.

Win32 "Desktop" applications get to use this set of [Edit_xxx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656457(VS.85).aspx) messages.

Comment: i don't think that's what i need - if i'm not wrong your answer will only force focus on my window, but i actually want to change the input mode (from numeric/textual/ and so on... )

thanks anyway though